# Reduce parsing time in Android

Tags: android

In my Android application I am following MVC pattern and I am receiving a large file from the server. I would like to update the UI as and when the parsing of one or two objects is done. I mean if I am receiving 20 movie objects from the server, on parsing I would like to display the content to user when 2 movies have been parsed and 2 movie objects are created. I am doing parser in a separate Parsing class and in activity I am calling my Async task.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Do you have to load those 20 movies in a single file or could you download 2 movies first and then the rest after that? That would make it easy to display the two movies before continuing downloads.

Comment: Code that i have is for parsing completely in my parser class and returns list of Movies object.What i require is from the server i will receive 20 movies at a stretch.While parsing i would like to parse it completely but update the user after obtaining 3 movie object.

Answer (score 0):

Your could add a method `downloadMoviesAsynchronously`:

```
public static interface MoviesDownloadedHandler {
    public void run(Movie[] movies);
}

public void downloadMoviesAsynchronously(final MoviesDownloadedHandler downloadedFirstTwo, final MoviesDownloadedHandler downloadedAll) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      int count = getMovieCount();
      Movie[] movies = new Movie[count];
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        movie[i] = downloadMovie();
        if (i == 1) // second movie
          downloadedFirstTwo.run(movies);
      }
      downloadedAll.run(movies);
    }
  }).start();
}
```

The UI then can call this method and specify some event handlers which update the UI.

Comment: Actually in my application all the list of movies come together in one json.I need the parser function like how to update the ui when every 3  movies have been parsed

Comment: How big is your json that it takes noticable time to be parsed? I don't think the video data itself is in the json string, so parsing surely does not take more than a second, does it?